# PDF resume not downloadable on react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add my resume to my portfolio as a downloadable PDF file. It works perfectly on a localhost but when I download from the hosted site the pdf download states "failed - No File". My code looks like this. ps. pdf and resume are defined and imported.

code:

```
import resume from "./resume.png"
import pdf from "./resume.pdf"

 <a href={pdf} download>Download</a>
 <a href={pdf}><img src={resume} alt="resume"/></a>
```

Comment: Hey man. I think we might need to see a working snippet. Are you able to pop your code onto something like stackblitz or jsfiddle please?

Comment: Here's the link to the page on my portfolio (http://ibrahim-mohamed-dev.surge.sh/resume) and that code in the question is exactly how my code looks on react.

Comment: I can't see the download link on your site but your JS is served from `/static/js`. Is your issue with pathing? If you try to open your file in browser what happens?

It also could be a file permissions issue. You may have deployed the image but your server isn't configured to serve it.

Comment: I've scrapped the whole downloadable resume idea and implemented a skills page instead. But nonetheless thank you so much for looking into this for me! I appreciate it!

Comment: All good man. Another interesting thing you might want to look at is that you can use a blob for your download so you wouldn't need a file path. You could just encode your PDF as a base64 string and store it in your JS. There's no huge advantage to it if your not dynamically creating download links but handy to know.